# How to search project name/id from local JSON in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Listing all project name and project id in side bar. You can see screen-1, how i am listing project.

[image]

Here project name and project id are loaded from local default.json. Now In search box, searching project id or project name. It list search result of project. You can see screen-2 screenshot.

[image]

Currently , I can able search text in search by giving static json response value in javascript. Here is the code which, I have tried of it.

```
  <script>
            $( function() {
            var projects= [
            {
            "instances": null,
            "name": "decodingideas",
            "projectid": "decodingideas-147616",
            "projectnumber": 334691107943,
            "orgid": "",
            "orgname": "",
            "parentid": "",
            "parenttype": ""
            },
            {
            "instances": null,
            "name": "pupil-workers",
            "projectid": "pupil-workers",
            "projectnumber": 455648594684,
            "orgid": "",
            "orgname": "",
            "parentid": "",
            "parenttype": ""
            }
            ];
        $( "#projects" ).autocomplete({
          source: function (request, response) {
              response($.map(projects, function (value, key) {
                    return {
                        label: value.name+" "+ value.projectid,
                        value: value.projectid
                    }
                }));

        }, 
          select: function(event, ui) {
              var res= $('#projects').val(ui.item.projectid);

              }
        });
      } );

</script>
```

Here is the search box html code:

```
<input id="projects" class="form-control form-control-dark w-100" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
```

Side bar project list html code:

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="col-md-2 d-none d-md-block bg-light sidebar">
      <div id="projectlist" class="sidebar-sticky" onclick="ClearFunction()">
        <ul class="nav flex-column nav-pills">

          {{range .Projects}}
          <li class="nav-item" >
            <a name="{{.ProjectID}}" class="nav-link" href="#">

              <img class="img-fluid" style="width:8%" 
 src="static/image/generic_gcp.png">
              {{.Name}}

              <div>
                <small>
                ProjectId: {{.ProjectID}}
              </small>
              </div>
            </a>
            </li>
            {{end}}

        </ul>

 <!-- Might need this seperator
        <h6 class="sidebar-heading d-flex justify-content-between align-items- 
 center px-3 mt-4 mb-1 text-muted">
          <span>Savings Reports</span>
        </h6>
      -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <main role="main" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 pt-3 px-4">
      {{range .Projects}}

      <div id={{.ProjectID}} class="d-none justify-content-between flex-wrap 
 flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom right-content">

        <h1 class="h2">Project:{{.Name}}</h1>
```

Selected static value json response in search box is not selecting in side bar and not showing details of thst selected project.

This is was getting right now: [image]

What exactly i need is this

[image]

Can anyone help me out of this!!

Comment: upload your code in the jsfiddle and send us the link to check.

Comment: @AnfathHifans ok can you check with above code

Comment: @PvDev jsfiddle is emty

Comment: @PvDev search does not work please update your code

Comment: @לבנימלכה it contains multiple css file i can share personally if possible

Comment: @PvDev show what you get in `res` when you select somthing

Comment: @לבנימלכה ok give mins

Comment: @PvDev I update jsfiddl to work one

Comment: @PvDev does it work now?

Comment: @לבנימלכה can you share the link

Comment: some link like you gave: https://jsfiddle.net/t2roa4n5/2/

Comment: could not able to identify what you have modified

Comment: @לבנימלכה any updates

Comment: can you share your email id @לבנימלכה

Comment: what do you use angularjs or angular 2+?? because I see you use `{{}}`

Comment: @לבנימלכה i have done this for getting JSON from local

Comment: @לבנימלכה use above link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I see in jsfiddle:
you will see it in bigger screen:

```js
  $( function() {
 var projects= [
{
"instances": null,
"name": "decodingideas",
"projectid": "decodingideas-147616",
"projectnumber": 334691107943,
"orgid": "",
"orgname": "",
"parentid": "",
"parenttype": ""
},
 {
"instances": null,
"name": "pupil-workers",
"projectid": "pupil-workers",
"projectnumber": 455648594684,
"orgid": "",
"orgname": "",
"parentid": "",
"parenttype": ""
}
];

    $( "#projects" ).autocomplete({
      source: function (request, response) {
           response($.map(projects, function (value, key) {
                return {
                    label: value.name+" "+ value.projectid,
                    value: value.projectid
                }
            }));
        
    }, 
      select: function(event, ui) {
           $('#projectId a small').text(ui.item.value);
           var name=ui.item.label.split(" ");
           $('#projectId a span').text(name[0]);
           var obj=projects.find(x=>x.projectid==ui.item.value);
           //$('#projectNumber a').text(obj.projectnumber);
           }
    });
  } );
```

```css
body {
  font-size: .875rem;
}

.feather {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
}

/*
 * Sidebar
 */

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  /* Behind the navbar */
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: inset -1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.sidebar-sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 48px;
  /* Height of navbar */
  height: calc(100vh - 48px);
  padding-top: .5rem;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  /* Scrollable contents if viewport is shorter than content. */
}

.sidebar .nav-link {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #333;
}

.sidebar .nav-link .feather {
  margin-right: 4px;
  color: #999;
}

.sidebar .nav-link.active {
  color: #fff;
  background: #007bff;
}

.sidebar .nav-link:hover .feather,
.sidebar .nav-link.active .feather {
  color: inherit;
}

.sidebar-heading {
  font-size: .75rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

/*
 * Navbar
 */

.navbar-brand {
  padding-top: .75rem;
  padding-bottom: .75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  box-shadow: inset -1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}

.navbar .form-control {
  padding: .75rem 1rem;
  border-width: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.form-control-dark {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
}

.form-control-dark:focus {
  border-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
}

/*
 * Utilities
 */

.border-top {
  border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

.border-bottom {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark sticky-top flex-md-nowrap p-0" style="background-color:#3B78E7">
  <a class="navbar-brand col-sm-3 col-md-2 mr-0" href="#">Projects</a>
  <input id="projects" class="form-control form-control-dark w-100" type="text"     placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
  <ul class="navbar-nav px-3">
    <li class="nav-item text-nowrap">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign out</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</nav>
 
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="col-md-2 d-none d-md-block bg-light sidebar">
      <div id="projectlist" class="sidebar-sticky">
        <ul class="nav flex-column nav-pills">
        <li class="nav-item" id="projectId">
         <a name="{{.ProjectID}}" class="nav-link" href="#">

                  <img class="img-fluid" style="width:8%" src="static/image/generic_gcp.png"/>
                  <span></span>

                  <div>
                    <small>
                    <!-- ProjectId: {{.ProjectID}} -->
                  </small>
                  </div>
                </a>
    </li>

          <!-- {{range .Projects}} -->


        </ul>

      </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```